# Symfony doctrine save data from form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to save data i get from form.

This is my UploadController.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use AppBundle\Entity\Photo;

class UploadController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $authChecker = $this->get('security.authorization_checker');

    if(!$authChecker->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('fos_user_security_login');
    }

    $form = $this->createForm('app_photo_upload', new Photo());

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()) {
       //save data
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle::upload.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
}
```

Upload Form Type

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class UploadFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder->add('name', 'file', array('data_class' => null));
    $builder->add('title', 'text');
    $builder->add('description', 'text');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_photo_upload';
    }
}
```

I should save the data from form, if the form is valid. What functions should i use to save data from form?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried reading the chapters on "Doctrine & Databases" & "Forms" in the Symfony Book? It's all there

Comment: you may want to read this article: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is standard addAction.

```
 public function addAction(Request $request) {

         $news = new News();

         $form = $this->createFormBuilder($news)
            ->add('title', 'text')
            ->add('body', 'text')
            ->add('save', 'submit')
            ->getForm();

         $form->handleRequest($request);    
         if ($form->isValid()) {
           $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
           $em->persist($news);
           $em->flush();
           return new Response('News added successfuly');
         }

         $build['form'] = $form->createView();
         return $this->render('FooNewsBundle:Default:news_add.html.twig', $build);
     }
```

So in your case you need to change form creation to this:

```
$photo = new Photo();
$form = $this->createForm('app_photo_upload', $photo);
```

and then:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
  $em->persist($photo);
  $em->flush();
}
```

I highly recommend you to use CRUD generator and then study the standard actions created by it:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html

Comment: The first change is not necessary, the current code is doing the same

Comment: As you see OP, you can skip first change. I was not sure about that till now. Thanks Carlos Granados for making it clear. :)